# Changing permissions on LinkedIn Login API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

We have a platform that uses LinkedIn to signup/in. There is a confusing permission that has been added by default into my list of permissions

w_member_social

This is causing our users to drop off because the description is 
"Manage your organization's page and post updates"

Does anyone know how/where I can change this? Searched far and wide without results.

Tried editing the API access params, tried making a new application (client/secret pair)

list of permissions should not have any write privileges i.e the following
1.) w_member_social
2.) rw_company_admin
3.) w_share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the permission scopes within your OAuth request to LinkedIn. If your use case is to Sign In with LinkedIn, your OAuth authorization request should resemble:

`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.yoursite.com/oauth2/callback&state=fooobar&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress`

Comment: Yea you were right. Update is : I was using the omiauth-linkedin gem and I needed to specify the scope in the initializer file. Thanks for the answer!